# Dynamic Node Addition/Updation on D3 js Network Graph on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm trying to add Nodes and Links between them on a Button click without loading any .Json file.

Here is **what i've done**: [Create Nodes/Links on document ready](https://jsbin.com/novocom/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var w = $("#graph").innerWidth();
var h = $("#graph").innerHeight();

var default_node_color = "#ccc";
var default_link_color = "red";
var nominal_base_node_size = 8;
var nominal_text_size = 10;
var max_text_size = 24;
var nominal_stroke = 1.5;
var highlight_stroke_width = 4;
var max_stroke = 4.5;
var min_zoom = 0.1;
var max_zoom = 7;
var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg");
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([min_zoom,max_zoom])
var g = svg.append("g");
svg.style("cursor","move");

var dnodes = [];
var dlinks = [];


function findNode(id) {
 for (var i in dnodes) {
  if (dnodes[i]["id"] === id) return dnodes[i];
  };
 };

function addNode(id,name) {
  var newNode = findNode(id);
  if(newNode == undefined) 
  {
   dnodes.push({"id":id,"name":name});   
   //update(dnodes,dlinks);
  }
  
        };
  
function addLink(sourceId, targetId) {
        var sourceNode = findNode(sourceId);
        var targetNode = findNode(targetId);
  if((sourceNode !== undefined) && (targetNode !== undefined)) {
            dlinks.push({"source": sourceNode, "target": targetNode});
   //update(dnodes,dlinks);
            }         
        };
 

addNode("1","2XYZ");
addNode("3","3XYZ");
addNode("4","4XYZ");
addNode("5","5XYZ");

addLink("1","2");
addLink("1","3");
addLink("1","4");
addLink("1","5");
 
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .linkDistance(160)
  .charge(-300)
  .friction(0.5)
  .size([w,h]);
 
var nodes = force.nodes(dnodes);
var links = force.links(dlinks);
  force.start();
//function update(dnodes, dlinks) 
//{
function isConnected(sourceNodeid, destNodeid)
 {
 
  for(var i in dlinks)
  {
   if((dlinks[i].source.id == sourceNodeid && dlinks[i].target.id==destNodeid)||((dlinks[i].source.id == destNodeid && dlinks[i].target.id==sourceNodeid)))
   {
    return true;
   }
   
  }
  if(sourceNodeid == destNodeid)
  {
  return true;
  }
  return false;
 }; 
  
 
  

function dragstart(d, i) {
 force.stop() // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
 }
function dragmove(d, i) {
 d.px += d3.event.dx;
 d.py += d3.event.dy;
 d.x += d3.event.dx;
 d.y += d3.event.dy; 
 tick(); 
 }

function dragend(d, i) {
 d.fixed = true; 
 tick();
 }
var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart)
        .on("drag", dragmove)
        .on("dragend", dragend);

var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(dlinks)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
 .style("stroke-width",nominal_stroke)
 .style("stroke", default_link_color)
 
  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(dnodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
 .call(node_drag);
  
  var circle = node.append("rect")
     .attr("x", "-15px")
     .attr("y", "-15px")
     .attr("rx", "4")
     .attr("ry", "4")
                    .attr("width", "30px")
     .attr("height", "30px")
                    .attr("id", function (d) {return d.id;})
                    .attr("fill", "#336699");
     
 var text = g.selectAll(".text")
      .data(dnodes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("y","22")
      .style("font-size", nominal_text_size + "px")
      text.text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("text-anchor", "middle");
      
     
  zoom.on("zoom", function() {
    var stroke = nominal_stroke;
    if (nominal_stroke*zoom.scale()>max_stroke) stroke = max_stroke/zoom.scale();
    link.style("stroke-width",stroke);
    circle.style("stroke-width",stroke);
 
 var text_size = nominal_text_size;
    if (nominal_text_size*zoom.scale()>max_text_size) text_size = max_text_size/zoom.scale();
    text.style("font-size",text_size + "px");
 g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
 });
  svg.call(zoom);   
  resize();
  force.on("tick", tick);
  
  function tick()
  {
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  text.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
 
 //node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }); 
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   
  }
  

   
  function resize() {
    var width = $("#graph").innerWidth();
 
 var height = $("#graph").innerHeight();
 svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    
 force.size([force.size()[0]+(width-w)/zoom.scale(),force.size()[1]+(height-h)/zoom.scale()]).resume();
    w = width;
 h = height;
 }
//}
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:none; padding:none; }
#graph { width:100%;height:100%; margin:auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

and Here is **What i'm trying to do**: [By Update function](https://jsbin.com/garuqez/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var w = $("#graph").innerWidth();
var h = $("#graph").innerHeight();

var default_node_color = "#ccc";
var default_link_color = "red";
var nominal_base_node_size = 8;
var nominal_text_size = 10;
var max_text_size = 24;
var nominal_stroke = 1.5;
var highlight_stroke_width = 4;
var max_stroke = 4.5;
var min_zoom = 0.1;
var max_zoom = 7;
var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg");
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([min_zoom,max_zoom])
var g = svg.append("g");
svg.style("cursor","move");

var dnodes = [];
var dlinks = [];


function findNode(id) {
 for (var i in dnodes) {
  if (dnodes[i]["id"] === id) return dnodes[i];
  }
 }

function addNode(id,name) {
  var newNode = findNode(id);
  if(newNode == undefined) 
  {
   dnodes.push({"id":id,"name":name});   
   update(dnodes,dlinks);
  }
  
        }
  
function addLink(sourceId, targetId) {
        var sourceNode = findNode(sourceId);
        var targetNode = findNode(targetId);
  if((sourceNode !== undefined) && (targetNode !== undefined)) {
            dlinks.push({"source": sourceNode, "target": targetNode});
   update(dnodes,dlinks);
            }         
        }
 

  $("#btnadd").click(function(){
    addNode("1","2XYZ");
    addNode("3","3XYZ");
    addNode("4","4XYZ");
    addNode("5","5XYZ");
    addLink("1","2");
    addLink("1","3");
    addLink("1","4");
    addLink("1","5");
  });


 
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .linkDistance(160)
  .charge(-300)
  .friction(0.5)
  .size([w,h]);
 
var nodes = force.nodes(dnodes);
var links = force.links(dlinks);

force.start();

function update(dnodes, dlinks) 
{
function isConnected(sourceNodeid, destNodeid)
 {
 
  for(var i in dlinks)
  {
   if((dlinks[i].source.id == sourceNodeid && dlinks[i].target.id==destNodeid)||((dlinks[i].source.id == destNodeid && dlinks[i].target.id==sourceNodeid)))
   {
    return true;
   }
   
  }
  if(sourceNodeid == destNodeid)
  {
  return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
  
 
  

function dragstart(d, i) {
 force.stop(); 
 }
function dragmove(d, i) {
 d.px += d3.event.dx;
 d.py += d3.event.dy;
 d.x += d3.event.dx;
 d.y += d3.event.dy; 
 tick(); 
 }

function dragend(d, i) {
 d.fixed = true; 
 tick();
 }
var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart)
        .on("drag", dragmove)
        .on("dragend", dragend);

var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data(dlinks)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
 .style("stroke-width",nominal_stroke)
 .style("stroke", default_link_color);
 
  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
    .data(dnodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
 .call(node_drag);
  
  var circle = node.append("rect")
     .attr("x", "-15px")
     .attr("y", "-15px")
     .attr("rx", "4")
     .attr("ry", "4")
                    .attr("width", "30px")
     .attr("height", "30px")
                    .attr("id", function (d) {return d.id;})
                    .attr("fill", "#336699");
     
 var text = g.selectAll(".text")
      .data(dnodes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("y","22")
      .style("font-size", nominal_text_size + "px")
      text.text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("text-anchor", "middle");
      
     
  zoom.on("zoom", function() {
    var stroke = nominal_stroke;
    if (nominal_stroke*zoom.scale()>max_stroke) stroke = max_stroke/zoom.scale();
    link.style("stroke-width",stroke);
    circle.style("stroke-width",stroke);
 
 var text_size = nominal_text_size;
    if (nominal_text_size*zoom.scale()>max_text_size) text_size = max_text_size/zoom.scale();
    text.style("font-size",text_size + "px");
 g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
 });
  svg.call(zoom);   
  resize();
  force.on("tick", tick);
  
  function tick()
  {
  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  text.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
 
 //node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; }); 
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   
  }
  

   
  function resize() {
    var width = $("#graph").innerWidth();
 
 var height = $("#graph").innerHeight();
 svg.attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
    
 force.size([force.size()[0]+(width-w)/zoom.scale(),force.size()[1]+(height-h)/zoom.scale()]).resume();
    w = width;
 h = height;
 }
}
});
```

```css
text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:none; padding:none; }
#graph { width:100%;height:100%; margin:auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.10/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="btnadd">Add</button>
  <div id="graph"></div>
 </body>
```

1st link code is working fine , 2nd link code is not working properly.
in 2nd link code i'm updating graph by `update()` function to add nodes on a button click.

`addNode()` `addLink()` i want to call on a button click. something like:

```
 $("#btnadd").click(function(){
addNode("1","2XYZ");
addNode("3","3XYZ");
addLink("1","2");
});
```

I'm not getting where i'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the update after each node insertion.

```
if(newNode == undefined) 
        {
            dnodes.push({"id":id,"name":name});   
            update(dnodes,dlinks);//don't do this
        }
```

Instead make all your nodes and links in the button click like this(commented below).

```
$("#btnadd").click(function() {
    addNode("1", "2XYZ");
    addNode("3", "3XYZ");
    addNode("4", "4XYZ");
    addNode("5", "5XYZ");

    addLink("1", "2");
    addLink("1", "3");
    addLink("1", "4");
    addLink("1", "5");
    update(dnodes, dlinks);//call your update function
    force.start();//you forgot to start the force layout.
});
```

working code [here](https://jsbin.com/wudafuburo/1/edit?js,output)